What's wrong with my fishing pond?
Image of artificial fishing pond requiring troubleshooting:

I've had success with this kind of strategy using water. My math says that's deep enough (nearly 20x5) it doesn't have anything blocking the surface of the honey. But I'm getting zero bites in there.  What have I missed? On PC.

The wiki only states that 50 connected tiles of honey are required in order for fishing to work, because I don't see anything wrong in your setup

Yeah it also says it's a minimum not a maximum or specific.
